# Python Binance - How to get the last PRICES traded in futures with websocket?

Tags: python, binance

I would like to get the last PRICES traded in futures with websocket, but I can only get the last mark prices of the futures using the next code:

```
BinanceWS = BinanceSocketManager(Binance)
conn_key = BinanceWS.start_symbol_mark_price_socket('BTCUSDT', MarketDataHandler)
BinanceWS.start()
```

Is there any command to get the last prices?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For futures prices you can use `start_symbol_ticker_futures_socket`